# find the coordinates from a distance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to determine whether there exists $5$ points in $\mathbb R^4$ such that the following matrix is the distance matrix.
  $$ \begin{pmatrix}
0& \sqrt5 &  \sqrt5 &  \sqrt5 & \sqrt5 \\
 \sqrt5 & 0&  2\sqrt5 &  2\sqrt2 & 2\\
\sqrt5  &2\sqrt5 & 0 & 2 & 2\sqrt2 \\
 \sqrt5 &  2\sqrt2 & 2 & 0 &2 \sqrt5 &\\
 \sqrt5 & 2 & 2\sqrt2 & 2 \sqrt5 &0\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$
I tried to assume that $x_0=(0,0,0,0)$, $x_1=(x_{11},0,0,0)$, $x_2=(x_{21}, x_{22}, 0,0)$, etc.. but I got stuck because I got $x_{22}=0$

Comment: Not a solution but perhaps a simplification. Notice that all points lie on the sphere of radius $\sqrt{5}$ around point $1$. Points $3$ and $2$ have distance $2\sqrt{5}$ so they are antipodal on the sphere. Same with points $4$ and $5$. This means that the points lie on two lines intersecting at point $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible.

So take $x_1$ and observe that the four other points are on the sphere of radius $\sqrt{5}$ centered at $x_1$.

Then note that
$$
\|x_2-x_3\|=\|x_4-x_5\|=2\sqrt{5}.
$$ 
So $x_2$ (resp $x_4$) is the symmetric of $x_3$ (resp $x_5$) with respect to $x_1$.

In particular, you should have ($[x_4,x_5]$ is diameter of the sphere, Pythagoras applies)
$$
\|x_4-x_5\|^2=\|x_4-x_2\|^2+\|x_2-x_5\|^2.
$$

But this yields $20=8+4$. So such points don't exist.